# How to use ColorScheme in FLutter ThemeData?

Tags: flutter, dart, material-ui, material-design, theming

I'm trying to create two color schemes, one for light mode and one for dark mode.
So in `main.dart` I returned this `MaterialApp` with `lightThemeData` and `darkThemeData`

```
return MaterialApp(
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: routesHandler,
  theme: lightThemeData(context),
  darkTheme: darkThemeData(context),
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
);
```

Then I created two `ThemeData` functions for light theme and dark theme and a `colorScheme` for each one, and this is how `lightThemeColors(context)` and `darkThemeColors(context)` looks like

```
ColorScheme lightThemeColors(context) {
  return const ColorScheme(
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primary: Color(0xFF202020),
    onPrimary: Color(0xFF505050),
    secondary: Color(0xFFBBBBBB),
    onSecondary: Color(0xFFEAEAEA),
    error: Color(0xFFF32424),
    onError: Color(0xFFF32424),
    background: Color(0xFFF1F2F3),
    onBackground: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
    surface: Color(0xFF54B435),
    onSurface: Color(0xFF54B435),
  );
}

ColorScheme darkThemeColors(context) {
  return const ColorScheme(
    brightness: Brightness.dark,
    primary: Color(0xFFF1F2F3),
    onPrimary: Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
    secondary: Color(0xFFBBBBBB),
    onSecondary: Color(0xFFEAEAEA),
    error: Color(0xFFF32424),
    onError: Color(0xFFF32424),
    background: Color(0xFF202020),
    onBackground: Color(0xFF505050),
    surface: Color(0xFF54B435),
    onSurface: Color(0xFF54B435),
  );
}
```

And these are the two `ThemeData` functions for light and dark theme

```
ThemeData lightThemeData(BuildContext context) {
  return ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
    textTheme: textTheme(context),
    appBarTheme: appBarTheme(context),
    inputDecorationTheme: inputDecorationData(context),
    colorScheme: lightThemeColors(context),
  );
}

ThemeData darkThemeData(BuildContext context) {
  return ThemeData(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
    textTheme: textTheme(context),
    appBarTheme: appBarTheme(context),
    inputDecorationTheme: inputDecorationData(context),
    colorScheme: darkThemeColors(context),
  );
}
```

Now the problem is in the `scaffoldBackgroundColor`, `appBarTheme` and `inputDecorationTheme`.

---

It just ignores the `scaffoldBackgroundColor` and uses the defualt one, which is `light blue`.

And in `appBarTheme` I tried to access the colors I defined earlier in the `colorScheme` function like this, but unfortunately nothing happens, and the `colorScheme` gets ignored.

```
appBarTheme(context) {
  return AppBarTheme(
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
    titleTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline5?.copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary),
  );
}
```

And the same happens in `inputDecorationTheme`, when I try to change the `fillColor` and the `hintStyle` color it ignores them as well.

```
InputDecorationTheme inputDecorationData(context) {
  return InputDecorationTheme(
    filled: true,
    fillColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onBackground,
    hintStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1?.copyWith(color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSecondary),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `lightThemeData`, you are calling `scaffoldBackgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme` which will return the default theme data as Theme widget does not exists by the time code is executed. In that case flutter returns default theme.

You should try using `scaffoldBackgroundColor: lightThemeColors(context).backgroundColor`